# How to make a preview layout which displays text entered in multiple textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed an add/remove textfield feature. I can add/remove textfields successfully.
Now I'm trying to create a preview of the values added in each textfield. So whenever I add a character in textfield it should be reflected in textfield each value in different lines.
I tried the following code, but this works for only the first textfield and not for the remaining ones.

```
$( document ).ready(function()
        {
            $(".row").find('input:text').keyup(function()
            {
                var word=$(this).val();
                alert(word);
                $(".word_preview").html(word);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Below is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/28h0L6eb/17/) I created for better understanding.In the fiddle you can see alert works for only first textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on("keyup",".row input[type='text']", function(){
        var word=$(this).val();
        alert(word);
        $(".word_preview").html(word);
                return false;
    });
});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28h0L6eb/28/)**

Comment: What you have done is correct, but when I type the second textbox, the contents of the first is gone. I want to keep the contents of both textfields

Comment: it will try once again. but if you submit this this will become blank